# Probability with replacement: 20 balls and 21 selections

Tags: probability

Here is the problem:

> There are $20$ balls labelled 1 through 20 in a basket. If you select $21$ balls (each time replacing the ball you selected), what is the probability that each number will be selected at least once?

I thought this was straightforward and here was my attempt:

Each number must show up at least once, this has probability

$(1/20)^{20}$

Then there will be a duplicate number which is free to be whatever number for the 21st ball:

$(1/20)^{20} \cdot (1/20)$

There are $20$ disjoint cases for the last number, so adding the above $20$ times gives

$(1/20)^{20}$

But this isn't correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: How many ways are there to draw the 1 twice, and each other ball once? Multiply that by 20. Divide by the number of ways to draw 21 balls from 20, with replacement.

Comment: So I guess the order which the balls are drawn does matter...I think I was under the assumption that it didnt which must have been where I was going wrong. Thanks

Comment: You’re welcome. These types of problems take a lot of practice. I’ve done many, and still have to think carefully about them each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the selected ball is replaced, we have $20$ options for each of the $21$ draws, so there are $20^{21}$ possible sequences of outcomes.

For the favorable cases, one number must appear exactly twice, with each of the other numbers occurring once.  Choose which number is repeated.  Choose which two of the $21$ positions in the sequence where that number occurs.  Arrange the remaining $19$ numbers in the remaining $19$ positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{20}{1}\binom{21}{2}19!$$
favorable cases.

Thus, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{20}{1}\binom{21}{2}19!}{20^{21}}$$

Comment: This is correct, thanks. Nice detailed explanation.